# Using XAMPP in Ubuntu while installing it in Fedora

Tags: xampp

I have downloaded and installed XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7 in fedora where it is running perfectly fine.
I also want it in ubuntu but donot want to giv up the disk space for installation once again but mount the folder /opt/lampp from fedora to /op/lampp in ubuntu.
i can mount it by using

```
sudo mkdir /opt/lampp && sudo mount --bind '/media/_Fedora-16-i686-/opt/lampp' /opt/lampp
```

and on running

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

from ubuntu i get

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

on running localhost on web browser i cant get past the splash page. how do I make this happen, so that i can do the same development from both the OS.

Comment: the hours it would take to get it working would pay for the thumb drive to hold the ubuntu mount point

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You need to install it again. You might however share the DocumentRoot.

Comment: And why cant i do that??, whats the reason??

Comment: AFAIK, It is doable. If not, try giving some reason for the answer.